# Determine whether a method has been called the first or the second time?

Tags: java

I want to implement a method which has a different behavior when called for the first time, and then when it is called for the second time.

How to do that?

Comment: have a static int as a counter

Comment: use flags and if you want to have counts use counters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instance methods in Java have access to the state of the class. Add a variable to indicate whether or not the methods has been called before, and use it to decide between two paths to take inside the method:

```
class FirstTimeCaller {
    private boolean isFirstTime = true;
    void methodWithState() {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            ... // Do first-time thing
            isFirstTime = false;
        } else {
            ... // Do the other thing
        }
    }
}
```

This works for instance methods of the same object: first-time call will be executed the first time you call `methodWithState` on each new object of `FirstTimeCaller` class.

If you wish to implement the same behavior for a static method, or you'd like to have the first invocation on *any* instance to do a different thing, and all subsequent calls to do something else, make `isFirstTime` field `static`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a variable

```
int counter = 0; // This means the method has not been called yet
```

And when the method is called then just do this code in it:

```
counter++; // Increment by 1 for each new call
```

And you have a number of method calls stored in a variable "counter" so you can choose what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to extend the list of possible solutions, you may as well consider the [State-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern):

```
public class Sandbox {

    private Runnable delegate = () -> {
        System.out.println("First Time");
        delegate = () -> System.out.println("Second Time");
    };

    public synchronized void doIt() {
        delegate.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MethodLogic implements Callable<String> {
    private boolean called = false;

    public String call() {
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            return "first";
        } else {
            return "not first";
        }
    }
}
```

Later use it like

```
Callable<String> method = new MethodLogic();
System.out.println(method.call());
System.out.println(method.call());
```

Answer (score 1):

If called in a multi-threaded context, you got to be careful with concurrent access. You can for instance use an AtomicBoolean:

```
public class FirstAndSecondTime {

    private static final AtomicBoolean FIRST_TIME = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public void perform() {
        if (FIRST_TIME.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            //execute first time logic here
        } else {
            //execute 2-n time logic here
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a static class:

```
public class MyStaticClass {
private static boolean firstTime = true;

public static void myMethod() {
    if (firstTime) {
        System.out.println("First time");
    } else {
        firstTime = false;
        System.out.println("NOT first time");
    }
}
```

}

Then you'd use it like this:

```
MyStaticClass.myMethod(); //-> prints "First time"
MyStaticClass.myMethod(); //-> prints "NOT first time"
MyStaticClass.myMethod(); //-> prints "NOT first time"
```

This is how the [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern does it with lazy initialization:

```
public final class Singleton {
private static Singleton instance = null;

private Singleton() {}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

You should probably not use this (unless you're using it for a Singleton, I guess), but use a field on an object:

```
public class MyMessagePrinter {
private int counter = 0;

public void printMessage() {
    if (this.counter > 0) {
        System.out.println("Fist time");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT first time");
    }
}
}
```

Using it like this:

```
MyMessagePrinter myPrinter = new MyMessagePrinter();
myPrinter.print(); //-> prints "First time"
myPrinter.print(); //-> prints "NOT first time"
myPrinter.print(); //-> prints "NOT first time"
```

Make note that the code is not [thread safe](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h033e/index.html)